# How do I change passive voice to active?

Tags: passive-voice

> The C# language will be used to test and create the application.

How would I remove the passive voice in this sentence?

Comment: Possibly you shouldn't. To remove the passive voice, you need to say ***who*** is going to create and test the application. If you know who, you should say *"John Doe's team will use the C# language to create and test the application"*. If you don't know or don't want to mention who will be doing it, then leave it in passive voice.

Comment: If you don't want a passive, you have to supply an agent subject, like _Methuselah will use the C# language to test and create the application._ The major reason for using passive is to avoid mentioning the agent.

Comment: @JohnLawler Hmm, I believe it's more a case of: *A* major reason for using the passive is to avoid mentioning the agent. *The* major reason for using the passive is to link the subject of the sentence with the previous discourse.

Comment: Oh, really? Are there studies?

Comment: @JohnLawler I believe several - from having to trawl through loads of information packaging guff in my previous existence. Pretty difficult to show *causes* though. You can only really show correlations. And give examples that back up the theory. Speaking of which, consider: "I've been studying the Mona Lisa. Leonardo Da Vinci pinted the Mona Lisa" which is not good. Now consider - "Ive been studying the Mona Lisa. The Mona Lisa was painted in 1503 (by Leonardo Da Vinci)". The "da Vinci" there makes little or no difference to the felicity of the two sentences together. ML's coming first does.

Comment: Well, there are certainly textual constraints on syntax -- there wouldn't be dozens of English rules moving stuff to the beginning or end of a clause if those weren't principal attention foci (the beginning because you parse and understand it first, and the ending because it's still in auditory memory and can be rehearsed). And certainly coreference isn't limited to one clause or sentence only. But choosing which rule to apply where is a very difficult decision that requires -- like most complicated systems -- a lot of experience and attention on the part of the speaker.

Comment: _They're going to use the C# language to test and create the application. Whatever will they think of next?_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the passive voice is to remove the agent (the person who does the test, in this case). The passive voice is used to describe what happens, not who does that.

Consequently, in order to change a passive-voice sentence into active voice, you need to supply a real subject: **who** will do the test and creation using C#.

> The C# language will be used to test and create the application.
>   **The team will use** the C# language to test and create the application.

Answer (score -1):

Some style guides will tell you to use the imperative case to remove the passive voice, as in: "Use the C# language to test and create the application."

Comment: But this doesn't mean the same thing at all.

Comment: Another suggestion.  Why not say that The subjects (Programmers) create C# Code to test and author the application.  The real downside to using active tense is that it does force you to name a subject.